# Iterate Through List with Seq and Variable

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, seq

I am attempting to loop through a list of integers starting out like so:

```
start=000
for i in $(seq -w $start 48 006);
```

However, when I try this code above, the loop seems to loop once and then quit.

What do I need to modify? (The leading zeroes need to stay)

Comment: Why do you want to use `seq`? Use the built-in math operators without forking external processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
start=0
diff=6
for i in $(seq $start $diff 48);
do
  printf '%03d\n' $i
done
```

Output will be as follows.

```
000
006
012
018
024
030
036
042
048
```

***Problem in OP's tried code:***
I believe you have given wrong syntax in `seq` it should be `startpoint` then `increment_number` then `endpoint` eg-->(`seq(start_point increment end_point)`). Since you have given them wrongly thus it is printing them only once in loop.

In your attempt it is taking starting point as 0 and should run till 6 with difference of 48 which is NOT possible so it is printing only very first integer value which is fair enough.

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per @Cyrus sir's comment adding BASH builtin solution here without using `seq`.

```
for ((i=0; i<=48; i=i+6)); do printf '%03d\n' $i; done
```

Comment: @hallettwx: with bash builtin commands: `for ((i=0; i<=48; i=i+6)); do printf '%03d\n' $i; done`

Answer (score 0):

`seq`'s input takes a start, increment-by, and finish.

You've reversed the increment-by with finish: `seq -w $start 48 006` means start at zero, increment by 48 to finish at 6. The simple fix is `seq -w $start 6 48`. Note: 006 is not needed, just 6 since `seq` will equalize the widths of the numbers to two places.